# CSS making tds overlap in a table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I don't understand why td overlaps in my table : http://jsfiddle.net/UEMgb/

```
table {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 60%;
    border-spacing:0px;
    margin:2%;
}

td {
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Comment: did you check your browser zoom? They look fine on my machine.

Comment: `width: 100%` + `padding`

Comment: @Mike On Chrome & on FF, `.argument` overlaps `.less`, no ?
@Mr.Alien what do you mean ?

Comment: The TDs aren't overlapping. It's the `<input>` elements you've got inside them that are. If you put `width: 100%` on the 2nd column's `<input type="text">`, things start looking better:

Comment: @muramasa He is talking about the default CSS box model. You are doing something, that only work in the altered box model which we known from MS IE 6. In these days you can use that box model by using the property `box-sizing` (see the links on my answer…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are setting the inputs to a width of 100% and then adding border and padding to it. You could maybe remove the width and set the inputs to `display: block;` or just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the input styles:

http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/UEMgb/1/

Pleaser refer to:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model

Answer (score 1):

Your `padding` .. on

```
.argument{
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

remove that, and might have to adjust `width` and `border` a tiny bit